# не запускается javaFX jar-ник

Tags: java, javafx, swing, eclipse

Сделал два эксперимента с использованием javaFx и Swing где оба этих проекта заворачиваю в банку (Eclipse). первым экспортировал Swing проект по двойному клику jar-ника все благополучно запускается, окно все дела и т. д. Но с javaFX проектом ни тут то было, делал все как положено, проверил все никаких ошибок, вот только не запускается и все, хотя запуская с командной строки оба работают стабильно.
Хотелось бы узнать кто сталкивался с такой проблемой именно с использованием javaFX ?

Comment: Какая версия java? на 8-ой версии должны работать, на более поздних вроде с этим беда

Comment: У меня 8 - я версия.

Comment: покажите командную строку, с помощью которой запускается нормально (для обоих jar'ников)